# What number comes after the Godaime Hokage?

Tags: naruto

I'll make a spoiler block of it all, since this can be a **spoiler to anyone who hasn't seen/read the Pain and the Five Kage Summit arcs**.

> After Pain's attack on Konoha, Tsunade exhausted her power and Danzo was nominated as Rokudaime Hokage. This lasted for a very short period (Danzo died fighting Sasuke) and Tsunade soon recovered and was, once again, appointed as the Hokage. **So next will/should come the Rokudaime again and Danzo should be ignored, or should we move on to the Shichidaime/Nanadaime (not sure about this) Hokage?**
>  I ask this because some people and [sites](http://www.leafninja.com/kage.php) consider Danzo only a temporary Hokage (in this logic we're still missing the 6th, so the next should be it). However, something similar has happened with the succession from 3rd (Hiruzen) to 4th (Minato) and back to 3rd (and later came Tsunade, the 5th). From this point of view, the next to succeed should be the seventh.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Uhm, this question is going to solicit speculation, I think because for example, I disagree with the answer. But both his and my answer are based on personal opinions, not facts.

Comment: Then, by all means, do present your argument in form of an answer. That is what I am looking for. Although, I am looking for substantiated answers, not just personal opinions. Or is this considered to be off-topic, because of the subjective pull of it?

Comment: Like I said, both our answer would be speculation. Well, probably Madara is right, but the question still asks something that we theoretically do not know yet.

Comment: Either way, I think this is the right time to be testing question regarding their validity in this site. So if it is closed I don't mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This is exactly the same case with the Third and the Fourth. The Third retired, and the Fourth was nominated. After the Fourth died, the Third retook the position, until the Fifth arrived.

> Conclusion: The next Hokage would probably be the Seventh.

A practical example would be [Ariel Sharon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariel_Sharon), the Israeli prime minister who fell to coma. He was replaced with Ehud Olmert, who is now referred to as an "ex-prime minister". He's also counted in the prime minister list.

Comment: On the other hand, Grover Cleveland is usually counted as the 22nd and 24th president of the United States, but I agree with you that Naruto seems to follow the convention you described.

Comment: Fairy Tail did a similar thing, where Markarov is listed as the Third, Sixth, and Eighth Masters. However, if we've already seen 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 3 - 5 already (instead of 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 3 - 6), you might see a Sixth hokage instead of a Seventh.

Answer (score 4):

As we now know, Danzo was only considered to be a temporary Sixth Hokage (*Rokudaime*).

> **After the Fourth Shinobi World War, Kakashi becomes Konoha's Sixth Hokage (Rokudaime Hokage)**
>  [image: Kakashi as Rokudaime]

Whereas:

> **Several years later, Kakashi decided to step down and selected Naruto to be the Seventh Hokage, thus making him the Nanadaime Hokage** [image]